# What does this mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am converting some Perl code to php, and I've stumbled on something, which I don't know for sure what it is.

```
if(!$continenttxt_cached{$savedcontinentid.'_'.$savedcountrygroupid})
```

What does the `{}` bracket do here? Is this a standard array element accessed this way? Because I am converting only a small part of a rather large code, I can't find how was `$continenttxt_cached` defined, so I can only presume this is an array. Is the `{}` used for something else in Perl?

Comment: its an hash value, `%continenttxt_cached` must be defined somewhere in your code

Comment: Not necessarily - if you don't `use strict;` and `use warnings;` a hash is implicitly created when you access it and set values in it. (This is bad style, but it can be done)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` in this context denotes a hash accessor - `hashes` are key-value pairs.

So you have a hash called `%continenttxt_cached` from which you're trying to extract the value associated with `$savedcontinentid.'_'.$savedcountrygroupid`

See [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for more information.

Comment: so this is basicaly like an associative array in php?

Comment: @Adam Baranyai, Yes, a hash is a kind of associative array. I don't know what type of associative arrays PHP uses, so the performance characteristics may be different.